# Do EMPs really have this property in the real world?

Tags: realism, the-matrix

In *The Matrix* (1999), the resistance uses EMPs to help them fight the machines:

> **Trinity:** Electromagnetic pulse. Disables any electrical system
> in the blast radius.

Do EMPs really have this property in the real world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse#Effects):

> A large and energetic EMP can induce high currents and voltages in the
> victim unit, temporarily disrupting its function or even permanently
> damaging it.